# Can i create android apps using javascript with facebook sdk?

Tags: javascript, android, facebook-javascript-sdk

Can i create smth  like this with JavaScript? Thank you very much for help

Create an Android application that allows to: 1. login to user's Facebook account and retrieve friends list. The list should be then displayed as given friend's profile image + username.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova would assist you in developing mobile applications for various platforms using javascript, html css. Here is their site url http://cordova.apache.org/
For facebook related stuff, You can use facebook's graph api.